# Как удалить из списка вложенные списки с одинаковыми элементами?

Tags: python, python-3.x, анализ-данных

Вот мой отрывок кода:

```
for i in range (1,10+1):

    if ( sum (elements) ) == i * 10:
        
        final_splitted_text.pop (k)
        break

k += 1
```

Cуть в чем допустим у нас есть массив со вложенными массивами, вот такого плана:
[[n1, ... , n10][n1, ... , n10 ]....около 2000 тысяч таких массивов], где n - это число в диапазоне от 1 до 10 и нам нужно удалить из него все вложенные списки, где все 10 числовых значений n с одинаковым числовым значением. Я пытался реализовать, как написано выше, но почему-то не работает.

Аннотация : массивы я выгрузил из таблицы корректно, но почему-то в конце не удаляются массивы с одинаковыми значениями.

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: Вероятно, вам нужно использовать set(). Если я правильно понял, то вам нужно что-то вроде: `res = [i for i in arr if len(set(i)) > 1]`. Если вы используете numpy, то вам стоит использовать `np.unique`

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Пример:

```
data = [[1,2,3], [1,1,1], [4,5,6], [3,3,3], [4,4,4]]
res = [x for x in data if any(y != x[0] for y in x)]
print(res)
>>> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```